# How to find the exact match between 2 vectors?

Tags: r

I need to find a match between 2 vectors:

```
y=c("13AD10","13AD11","13AD12","13AD13","13AD14","13AD16","13AD17","13AD19","13AD1","13AD20","13AD21","13AD24","13AD25","13AD2","13AD3","13AD5","13AD6","13AD7","13AD8","13AD9","13HD10","13HD11","13HD12","13HD14","13HD5","13HD7")
to_find=c("13AD1","13AD3","13AD7","13AD13","13AD20")
```

Based on what I found on this site, I tried

```
select=grep(paste(to_find,collapse="|"),y)
```

which returns too many entries (everything starting with 13AD1 is there)

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 15 18
```

I tried

```
select=which(y==to_find)
```

but not all entries are included

```
[1]  4 10 18
```

Indeed, I get this

```
y==to_find
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[21] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Despite the fact that for example

```
to_find[1]==y[9]

[1] TRUE
```

I am quite confuse, why do I get different results for y==to_find and to_find[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827300/matching-up-two-vectors-in-r)==y[9] ? Any idea on how to get the exact match between my vectors? Thanks for your help.

PS: the question is partially answered there [Matching up two vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827300/matching-up-two-vectors-in-r) but that post doesn't include the explanation about grep and ==

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
which(y %in% to_find)
# [1]  4  9 10 15 18
which(to_find %in% y)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: with this approach it is not immediately clear which index corresponds to which value in `to_find` (unless of course OP doesn't care). `match(to_find, y)` below is a better option i think

Comment: @stasg You are right

Answer (score 5):

how about:

```
to_find %in% y
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

to_find[to_find %in% y]
# [1] "13AD1"  "13AD3"  "13AD7"  "13AD13" "13AD20"
```

`grep(paste(to_find,collapse="|"),y)` gives you "too many" answers because for example `13AD1` would get matched to `13AD10` because the former is wholly featured in the latter.

`which(y==to_find)` gives you "too few" answers because it looks at pairwise equality (and vector `to_find` is recycled to match the length of `y`), so `i` will be returned only if `to_find[i] == y[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This doesn't exactly work actually. I need the positions of "to_find" in "y". The answer should be  [1] 4 9 10 15 18

Comment: @matarit that wasn't clear from your question. then jogo's answer below will give you exactly that. however my explanation of why your approaches didn't work still stands

Comment: Thank you @stas g for your explanations.

Comment: @Matarit no problem:)

Answer (score 4):

This will give you the indices of the elements of `to_find` in `y`:

```
> match(to_find, y)
[1]  9 15 18  4 10

> match(c(to_find, "hallo"), y)
[1]  9 15 18  4 10 NA
```

you can sort the result:

```
> sort(match(c(to_find, "hallo"), y))
[1]  4  9 10 15 18
```