# matching "sub-vectors" in R

Tags: r, vector, matching

so R has a great function, match, to find values in vectors (also %in% to test the existence). but what if I want to find a short vector in a big vector? that is, to test if a given vector is contained (in order!) in another vector? what if I want to find whether a given vector is a prefix/suffix of another vector? are there such functions in R?

example of what I would like:

```
x=c(1,3,4)
y=c(4,1,3,4,5)
z=c(3,1)

v_contains(x,y)  # return TRUE x is contained in y
v_contains(z,y)  # FALSE the values of z are in y, but not in the right order
v_match(x,y)     # returns 2 because x appears in y starting at position 2
```

is there anything like it? how would you approach it efficiently?

Comment: You can use `match` for this too, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827300/matching-up-two-vectors-in-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [recent post](https://coolbutuseless.bitbucket.io/2018/04/03/finding-a-length-n-needle-in-a-haystack/) uncovered this solution by Jonathan Carroll. I doubt a faster solution exists in R.

```r
v_match <- function(needle, haystack, nomatch = 0L) { 
  sieved <- which(haystack == needle[1L]) 
  for (i in seq.int(1L, length(needle) - 1L)) {
    sieved <- sieved[haystack[sieved + i] == needle[i + 1L]]
  }
  sieved
}

v_contains <- function(needle, haystack) {
  sieved <- which(haystack == needle[1L]) 
  for (i in seq.int(1L, length(needle) - 1L)) {
    sieved <- sieved[haystack[sieved + i] == needle[i + 1L]]
  }
  length(sieved) && !anyNA(sieved)
}
```

Tests and benchmarks:

```r
library(testthat)
x=c(1,3,4)
y=c(4,1,3,4,5)
z=c(3,1)

expect_true(v_contains(x,y))   # return TRUE x is contained in y
expect_false(v_contains(z,y))  # FALSE the values of z are in y, but not in order
expect_equal(v_match(x,y), 2)  # returns 2 because x appears in y starting at position 2

x <- c(5, 1, 3)
yes <- c(sample(5:1e6), c(5, 1, 3))
no <- c(sample(5:1e6), c(4, 1, 3))
expect_true(v_contains(x, yes))
expect_false(v_contains(x, no))
expect_equal(v_match(x, yes), 1e6 - 3)


v_contains_roll <- function(x, y) {
  any(zoo::rollapply(y, length(x), identical, x))
} 
v_contains_stri <- function(x, y) {
  stringr::str_detect(paste(y, collapse = "_"),
                      paste(x, collapse = "_"))
}

options(digits = 2)
options(scipen = 99)
library(microbenchmark)
gc(0, 1, 1)
#>           used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
#> Ncells  527502   28    1180915   63   527502   28
#> Vcells 3010073   23    8388608   64  3010073   23
microbenchmark(v_contains(x, yes), 
               v_contains(x, no),
               v_contains_stri(x, yes),
               v_contains_stri(x, no),
               v_contains_roll(x, yes),
               v_contains_roll(x, no), 
               times = 2L,
               control = list(order = "block"))
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                     expr    min     lq   mean median     uq    max neval
#>       v_contains(x, yes)    3.8    3.8    3.8    3.8    3.9    3.9     2
#>        v_contains(x, no)    3.7    3.7    3.7    3.7    3.8    3.8     2
#>  v_contains_stri(x, yes) 1658.4 1658.4 1676.7 1676.7 1695.0 1695.0     2
#>   v_contains_stri(x, no) 1632.3 1632.3 1770.0 1770.0 1907.8 1907.8     2
#>  v_contains_roll(x, yes) 5447.4 5447.4 5666.1 5666.1 5884.7 5884.7     2
#>   v_contains_roll(x, no) 5458.8 5458.8 5521.7 5521.7 5584.6 5584.6     2
#>  cld
#>  a  
#>  a  
#>   b 
#>   b 
#>    c
#>    c
```

<sup>Created on 2018-08-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>

Comment: this is cool. marking it as correct appreciating the thoroughness of the answer (as well as liking the needle in the haystack metaphor). However, I'm not sure this is the most efficient r code I could think of. I will try a few improvments and post them if successful.

Answer (score 1):

```
x=c(1,3,4)
y=c(4,1,3,4,5)
z=c(3,1)

# 1. return TRUE x is contained in y

stringr::str_detect(paste(y, collapse = "_"), paste(x, collapse = "_"))

# 2. FALSE the values of z are in y, but not in the right order

all(z %in% y) & stringr::str_detect(paste(y, collapse = "_"), paste(z, collapse = "_"))

# 3. returns 2 because x appears in y starting at position 2

stringr::str_locate(paste(y, collapse = "_"), paste(x, collapse = "_"))[1] - 1
```

Comment: it is true that string matching is kind of what i need, but with vectors - mapping my vectors to strings, should do the job... BUT
this will not work for large vectors due to memory and runtime demands.

Answer (score 0):

If `x` and `y` are as in the question then here are some alternatives.

**1) rollapply**  This checks if `x` is contained in `y`.

```
library(zoo)

any(rollapply(y, length(x), identical, x))
## [1] TRUE
```

**2) embed**  Slightly more complex but still one line and no package dependencies.

```
any(apply(t(embed(y, length(x))) == rev(x), 2, all))
## [1] TRUE
```

**2a)** or this variation:

```
any(apply(embed(y, length(x)), 1, identical, rev(x)))
## [1] TRUE
```

**3) strings**  Convert both `x` and `y` into character strings and use `grepl`.  The comments to the question already point to code for such an approach.

**4) Rcpp** If speed is important then we can code it in C++. The standard library already has this as a builtin.  Place this in a file `Search.cpp` in the current directory and from within R run `library(Rcpp); sourceCpp("Search.cpp")`.  Then the R code `Search(x, y)` will invoke it.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool Search(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  return search(begin(y), end(y), begin(x), end(x)) != end(y);
}
```